# Newbie question on syntax and type signature in Haskell/HappStack

Tags: haskell, happstack

Why is it that I can't do

```
z = x?
```

but I can do this?

```
y s = x s
```

I'm a Haskell newbie
This is what I've been trying in GHCi:

```
Prelude> import Happstack.Server
Prelude Happstack.Server> let x s = ok $ toResponse $ "Some string"
Prelude Happstack.Server> :t x
x :: FilterMonad Response m => t -> m Response

Prelude Happstack.Server> let y s = x s
Prelude Happstack.Server> :t y
y :: FilterMonad Response m => t -> m Response

Prelude Happstack.Server> let z = x
<interactive>:1:9:
    No instance for (FilterMonad Response m0)
      arising from a use of `x'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like another case of the [monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction).

You can either include the argument explicitly, i.e. `y s = x s`, include an explicit type signature, or run GHCi with `-XNoMonomorphismRestriction`.

Comment: Thanks. It works =)
Although I think it'll be a few months before I understand what that means, and what I'm giving away by using that flag.